# What does model.summary in keras means?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I am new to keras and have obtained the following information of my model.

```
=================================================================
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 66, 1)             0         
                                                                 
 conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 66, 32)            128       
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D  (None, 33, 32)           0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 33, 64)            6208      
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 17, 64)           0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 1088)              0         
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 1088)              0         
                                                                 
 y_pred (Dense)              (None, 2)                 2178      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 8,514
Trainable params: 8,514
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I understand that for the output shape none it means the batch size, while the 32 in conv1d is the output of the layer. How about 66 in conv1d is it the input shape of conv1d?

````
model.add(Reshape((int(input_length / 1), 1), input_shape=(input_length, )))

model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))

model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))

model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='y_pred'))```
````

Comment: The values are: batch size, input size (1d, 2d ...) and depth.

Comment: I see so for example (None, 66, 32)
none= batch size, 66= input size to that layer, 32= the depth or number of neurons in that layer?

Comment: yes, that's the sizes

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Mahrkeenerh is not correct.
The 66 in the example is the **output size**, whilst I would rather call the 32 the output dimension or amount of kernels (in convolutional context).

Comment: So you mean 66 is the output size of the layer at the end of that layer  and 32 is the number of kernels or neurons for that layer?

Comment: Exactly. Thats why max pooling layers reduce the 66 (They take the maximum of 2 input neurons) and conv layer do not (as long as stride=1).